# Problem creating a CiviCase via online form

Tags: custom-fields, civicase

I want a user to be able to order various stickers from our website. They are distributed for free, but in exchange we request photos of where people put them. To track the whole process of application, mailing, communications, reminders, and receiving the photos back, we need to create a CiviCRM Case.
However, I'm not able to display such a Profile on the website (Wordpres 5.8.2, CiviCRM 5.38). Turns out, the сustom fields set I've created for various stickers' selection is not even listed among profiles I can put online via the CiviCRM button (which inserts the code like [civicrm component="profile" gid="32" mode="create" hijack="0"]).
Is there a way to open a case through an online form?

Comment: since civicase adds a layer of complexity, would it be worth discussing (eg in a diff. question on here) how to achieve what you want using only Activities?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use civi's profiles with cases this way, partly because you'd want to collect some contact data as well and you can't mix in a profile.

In drupal I would say use webform_civicrm. For wordpress I believe caldera/ninja forms can do cases but there was some talk about it being discontinued at some point.

Comment: Can I collect user data in one profile, the stickers data in the other and then somehow link it to a CiviCase?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure yet, but the 'Form processor' direction looks very promising to explore. https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external.

At least it can open a CiviCase for a user who has just entered his name and email.